# Azure connectivity and Access error error code 403

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

**Error 1**: Failed to load one or more resources due to no access, error code 403.
I checked with the [answers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjvhNyYlJj9AhXSMlkFHezVDn8QFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F69076072%2Faccess-issue-with-azure-synapse-studio&usg=AOvVaw2p43aeRl225AQpkt4YGLrO) here but they don't work for me. As the screenshots below suggest, I am the service administrator, owner and contributor of the Synapse workspace. I also allow public access to the Synapse workspace.

[image: my role assignment]

[image: allow public access]

**Error 2**: If I check the access control on Synapse studio portal, it says I am not the synapse administrator but I am actually the service administrator of the entire subscription.
[image: Contact a Synapse Administrator]

**Error 3**: Cannot create an SQL pool. [image: Cannot create an SQL pool]

Answer (score 0):

The Azure IAM/RBAC roles are for working with the Azure resource, but the Synapse workspace also has its own access control. You will need to grant permissions/RBAC inside the workspace itself. [[documentation]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-set-up-access-control)

I recommend using Groups to manage permissions, but you can start by adding yourself as a Synapse Administrator.

Comment: The first screenshot I showed up is actually from the access control in Azure portal -> Synapse workspace. Is it different from the access control inside the workspace itself? Sorry I am still quite new to Azure. Thanks!

Comment: @Joel Cochran - Could you please clear cookies & cache of the browser and re-try or try New Incognito mode?

Comment: @Anonny - yes, they are different. I think of the Azure one as "external" and the Synapse one as "Internal". You need to account for them both, but they cover different areas of responsibility.

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT I have tried cleaning the caches and incognito mode as well. Neither works.

Answer (score 0):

> For Error1: You may try the following steps and let us know.

[image]

This article - [Disabling Public Network Access in Synapse](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/disabling-public-network-access-in-synapse/ba-p/3692197) helps to resolve the issue.

> For Error2:Make sure you have `Synapse Administrator` role in the Manage => Security => Access Control

[image]

For more details, refer to [Grant access to SQL pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-set-up-access-control#step-7-grant-access-to-sql-pools).

Comment: Error 1: I have tried the incognito mode and it does not work. Error 2: I am the subscription administrator but I am not and cannot be assigned the Synapse administrator role for some unknown reason.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "cannot be assigned Synapse Administrator role"?